# Having multiple animations at the same time CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Depending on my environment, the following animation is either aligned (color of charts DOES NOT change during the animation) or completely off.

I suspect this is due to me starting multiple animations and they start at different times.

How would you align the animations / force them to start at the same time?
+
I need to change some values in the keyframes without actually animating them (in this case, the color) - thus, I created several steps at .99% and transition them to the next full number - is this the correct approach?

```css
@keyframes swinging {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(-65deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
  0.01%{
    transform: rotate(-65deg);
    opacity: 1;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
  30%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
  99.99%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }
}
@keyframes changeContent{
    0%{
      color: #fbd977;
      content: "\f1fe";
  }
  19.99% {
    content: '\f1fe';
    color: #fbd977;
  }
    20.00%{
      color: #ed9286;
      content: "\f201";
    }
  39.99% {
      content: "\f201";
    color: #ed9286;
  }
    40.00%{
      color: #d992bc;
      content: '\f200';
    }
  59.99% {
      content: '\f200';
    color: #d992bc;
  }
    60.00%{
      color: #84bbe6;
      content: '\f080';
    }
  79.99% {
       color: #84bbe6;
      content: '\f080';
  }
    80.00%{
      color: #aed292;
      content: '\f0ce';
    }
  99.99% {
      color: #aed292;
      content: '\f0ce';
  }
}

.fa:before {
            animation: changeContent calc(15s/3) infinite;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 5em!important;
 animation: swinging calc(3s/3) cubic-bezier(0,2,.58,1) forwards infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="loading">
  <span class="foo fa-fw fa fa-area-chart"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: So is the code working as expected or not?

Comment: I personally never been able to get CSS animations timed properly when trying to fire multiple animations at the same time. These days I just use greensock to manage all CSS animations. A lot more precise and a lot more control options. Might be a solution worth looking into.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski it is to some degree - in this demo environment it works. But if I have to load fontawesome asynchronously, or put the code in a different environment - it will not be in sync.

Comment: @Frame91 Can't you use JavaScript to add the animation after fontawesome loads?

Comment: yes - I could, but given that I'd like to have it available in several places (+different applications) I'd rather have a more generic solution in CSS only. But if I don't see a good solution I'm definitely going with Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably merge them into only one animation that you can easily manage without any synchronisation issue.

```css
@keyframes changeContent {
  0% {
    color: #fbd977;
    content: "\f1fe";
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  19.99% {
    content: '\f1fe';
    color: #fbd977;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20.00% {
    color: #ed9286;
    content: "\f201";
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  39.99% {
    content: "\f201";
    color: #ed9286;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40.00% {
    color: #d992bc;
    content: '\f200';
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  59.99% {
    content: '\f200';
    color: #d992bc;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60.00% {
    color: #84bbe6;
    content: '\f080';
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  79.99% {
    color: #84bbe6;
    content: '\f080';
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80.00% {
    color: #aed292;
    content: '\f0ce';
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  99.99% {
    color: #aed292;
    content: '\f0ce';
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.fa:before {
  animation: changeContent 10s infinite;
  display:inline-block; /* Don't forget this to be able to use transform */
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 5em!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="loading">
  <span class="foo fa-fw fa fa-area-chart"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about combining both animations. Exactly what I need in this scenario.